# Create table in shell script

Tags: sh

I would like to create a table in a shell script who contain images in ASCII arts without using a text file.
For information, the shell script create an rst file which itself create a pdf and html file.
thank

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
myArt='
   /_o_\
     |
    / \
'

echo "$myArt"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but the picture come to web and use the command jp2a who transform the picture

Comment: You will need to give us more details about what the code may look like, for us to further help.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPtWs.png)

I would like create this table whithout using text file 
from shell script